# How to generate objects on a window by a button click

Tags: c++, qt

I want a simple example code that shows QLineEdits by a QPushButton click on the same window. i.e. Whenever the button is clicked, a new line edit is displayed on the window.
Or if i should put it this way; if the button is clicked 4 times, 4 line edits should be displayed on that same window 
Thank you!

Comment: I tried including the line edit in a layout and using setHidden(1) on it. Then creating a slot that changes it to setHidden(0) when the button is clicked but it only displays it once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions is to create a `QVector` of pointers to `QLineEdit` and to add new one each time button is clicked. Each new created `QLineEdit` has to be added to your window layout. Like this:

```
QVector<QLineEdit*> lineEdits;

void onButtonClick() {
    QLineEdit* newLineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
    lineEdits.push_back(newLineEdit);
    // Add newLineEdit to layout
}
```

Don forget to delete the elements when they're not needed or use smart pointers.

Comment: I thought of that after reading around but the problem is i don't know how to implement it. That is why i asked for an example code

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll test it when i can so i give you feed back